# UbuntuStudio23.10 - Ubuntu Studio Audio Configuration

Tags: ubuntu-studio

Who can explain what the tool "Ubuntu Studio Audio Configuration" with the chapter "Disable Pipe Wires JACK Emulation" exactly do?

[image]

The native jackd is installed in both cases and pipewire-jack too. So this tool makes some settings in some other configuration files?
Best Regards
Guenter